# Shape_area and ALAND AWATER in Tiger census data

Tags: gis, arcgis, qgis, esri, tiger-census

What does Shape_area mean? I noticed that it is not the sum of Aland and Awater. What are the units of these three?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The units of ALAND and AWATER are square meters. E.g., `tl_2015_us_county.dbf` has a record for Cuming County with `ALAND = 1477895811` and `AWATER = 10447360`. From [Wikipedia](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CG4QmhMwDmoVChMI2Nqn77zZyAIVSsljCh3ZngLc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCuming_County%2C_Nebraska&usg=AFQjCNGCtPeW4QtLKSaL29QGoC6Iu3KYKQ&bvm=bv.105841590,d.cGc) the area is `575 mi^2`. If you convert `575 mi^2` to sq. meters you get same result as `ALAND + AWATER`

Answer (score 2):

Squared meters as the docs specifies:
https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/fact/note/US/LND110210