# Calculating the area of census tracts from multipolygons in R

Tags: r, arcgis, tidycensus

I am trying to calculate the area of each census tract in the United States. I used tidycensus to extract a multipolygon for each census tract with its coordinates.

```
library(tidycensus)
library(purrr)

census_api_key("KEY")

us <- unique(fips_codes$state)[1:51]
geometry <- map_df(us, function(x) {
  get_acs(geography = "tract", variables = "B19013_001", geometry = TRUE, 
          state = x)
})
```

None of the methods I have been able to find for calculating the area of a multipolygon work with lists, which is the format tidycensus stores the coordinates in. Is there another format that would be easier to use? Is there some way of calculating the area using coordinates in this format?

I have tried gArea() from the rgeos package, area() from the raster package, st_area() from the sf package, and polyarea() from the geometry package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating area of a multipolygon using `sf::st_area()` is working fine for me. Here's an example of downloading data from `tidycensus` and calculating the area of all census tracts in Vermont.

```r
library(tidycensus)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

vt_tracts <- get_acs(
  geography = "tract",
  variables = "B19013_001",
  geometry = TRUE,
  state = "VT"
)

vt_tracts %>% 
  mutate(area = st_area(.))
#> Simple feature collection with 184 features and 6 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -73.43774 ymin: 42.72685 xmax: -71.46455 ymax: 45.01666
#> CRS:            4269
#> First 10 features:
#>          GEOID                                       NAME   variable estimate
#> 1  50001960100 Census Tract 9601, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    78750
#> 2  50001960200 Census Tract 9602, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    74958
#> 3  50001960300 Census Tract 9603, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    59464
#> 4  50001960400 Census Tract 9604, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    78672
#> 5  50001960500 Census Tract 9605, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    56066
#> 6  50001960600 Census Tract 9606, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    58343
#> 7  50001960700 Census Tract 9607, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    53910
#> 8  50001960800 Census Tract 9608, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    66713
#> 9  50001960900 Census Tract 9609, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    65515
#> 10 50001961000 Census Tract 9610, Addison County, Vermont B19013_001    62763
#>      moe                       geometry            area
#> 1   8764 POLYGON ((-73.1968 44.26663... 212702063 [m^2]
#> 2   8731 POLYGON ((-73.39963 44.1553... 158329687 [m^2]
#> 3  10068 POLYGON ((-73.27275 44.1768...   6614856 [m^2]
#> 4   4139 POLYGON ((-73.43774 44.0450... 359804506 [m^2]
#> 5  10897 POLYGON ((-73.1495 44.17669... 109378523 [m^2]
#> 6   3601 POLYGON ((-73.06466 44.0408... 530756434 [m^2]
#> 7   7404 POLYGON ((-73.16763 44.0289...  70741373 [m^2]
#> 8  10440 POLYGON ((-73.19061 44.0189...  30961721 [m^2]
#> 9   4949 POLYGON ((-73.41258 43.9827... 478027734 [m^2]
#> 10  7192 POLYGON ((-73.18767 43.8964... 134156214 [m^2]
```

Although to answer your more narrow question about finding the area of US Census tracts, you could use the [`tigris` pacakge](https://github.com/walkerke/tigris) (which is what `tidycensus` uses under the hood to pull geometry), which in addition to the geometry, returns the land area (`ALAND`) and water area (`AWATER`) of each tract (or any other geography requested) directly from the Census files.

```r
tigris::tracts(state = "VT", class = "sf")

#> Simple feature collection with 184 features and 12 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -73.4379 ymin: 42.72693 xmax: -71.46505 ymax: 45.01666
#> CRS:            4269
#> First 10 features:
#>    STATEFP COUNTYFP TRACTCE       GEOID NAME          NAMELSAD MTFCC FUNCSTAT
#> 1       50      007  000600 50007000600    6    Census Tract 6 G5020        S
#> 2       50      007  000800 50007000800    8    Census Tract 8 G5020        S
#> 3       50      007  000900 50007000900    9    Census Tract 9 G5020        S
#> 4       50      007  001100 50007001100   11   Census Tract 11 G5020        S
#> 5       50      001  960400 50001960400 9604 Census Tract 9604 G5020        S
#> 6       50      001  960900 50001960900 9609 Census Tract 9609 G5020        S
#> 7       50      001  960500 50001960500 9605 Census Tract 9605 G5020        S
#> 8       50      001  961000 50001961000 9610 Census Tract 9610 G5020        S
#> 9       50      001  960600 50001960600 9606 Census Tract 9606 G5020        S
#> 10      50      001  960300 50001960300 9603 Census Tract 9603 G5020        S
#>        ALAND   AWATER    INTPTLAT     INTPTLON                       geometry
#> 1    2240206   147061 +44.4833940 -073.1936217 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.20609 4...
#> 2    1349586        0 +44.4609464 -073.2086195 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.21524 4...
#> 3     602429        0 +44.4714041 -073.2088310 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.21393 4...
#> 4    1736310        0 +44.4509355 -073.2197727 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.23253 4...
#> 5  321773486 38567561 +44.0870615 -073.2671642 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.43771 4...
#> 6  456817599 21511403 +43.9055842 -073.2904483 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.41251 4...
#> 7  107525416  1714148 +44.0978095 -073.0485314 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.1487 44...
#> 8  128778705  5371192 +43.9008582 -073.1035817 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.18875 4...
#> 9  528821667  1880822 +43.9987500 -072.9398701 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.06466 4...
#> 10   6413118   203405 +44.1632873 -073.2485362 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.27275 4...
```

Comment: nice answer. do you know if the calculated areas match with ALAND or ALAND+AWATER?

Comment: it is ALAND+AWATER https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246602/shape-area-and-aland-awater-in-tiger-census-data